# Minesweeper, how can i work on cells

Tags: java, swing

I would like to create a minesweeper game. Firstly, this will work on buttons. I think I will work on two dimensional array, and there will be like boolean array that will present where are bombs, for example if booleanArray[0][4] is true, there is a bomb.

Now, how can I implement this in my buttons? I can set Names on these buttons, and then if I click some button, then I will get the name from this div. For example when i click first button, i will get "00" name, then i will get first letter "0" and second letter "0" and parse it to int. And this will be the indexes from my previous booleanArray, in this case it will be booleanArray[0][0].

So, can I do this another, better way, instead of that?

This is the way I will be creating the buttons:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            JButton button = new JButton("");
            button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
            button.setName(Integer.toString(i) + Integer.toString(j));
           }
     }
```

EDIT

 I will have a two dimensional Array, that will reflect my buttons:
[image]

and now, how can I check if I hit the bomb after I click for example in the first button?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but in your code, the JButton objects will immediately go out of scope on the next iteration of your loop.  Maybe you want a 2 dimensional JButton array?

Comment: Hi, I edited my post. Please check if you know what I am talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hold a two dimensional array of buttons,

```
JButton[][] myButtons = new JButton[10][10];
```

which you use to draw them and they all call the same method with their value

```
 for (int x=0; x<10; x++){
   for (int y=0; y<10; y++){
     myButtons[x][y] = new JButton("0");
     //add to page, or do it elsewhere
     myButtons[x][y].addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
           selectionButtonPressed(x,y);
        }
     });
   }
 }
```

Then a call to yout method `selectionButtonPressed()` will tell you what button has been pressed, you can take action and even make changes to the button with `myButtons[x][y].whatever()`

Answer (score 1):

That is one way but you should create the String of the name by using something like:

```
button.setName(i + ":" j);
```

This will make it easier to parse out the two values as you can just use the `String.split(...)` method.

Another option might be to create a `HashTable` with the `JButton` as the key and then use a `Point` object (representing the row/column) as the value Object of the `HashTable`. Then you just use the `get(...)` method of the HashMap to retrieve the Point for the clicked button.

Another option is to extend JButton and add two parameters (row, column) when creating the button. Then you also add `getRow()` and `getColumn()` methods.

Either of this approaches will keep the logic simple and you only need to create a single ActionListener to be used by all the buttons.